# Verbatim with Wrapping?

Tags: verbatim, wrap

I want to copy/paste some text in my latex file as is. I use \begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}

The problem is when I copy long text like the following, the text is rendered in one line which exceeds the page. Is there any option to wrap the long text automatically?

the sample:

curl -v -s -X POST $OS_AUTH_URL/auth/tokens?nocatalog   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d '{ "auth": { "identity": { "methods": ["password"],"password": {"user": {"domain": {"name": "'"$OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME"'"},"name": "'"$OS_USERNAME"'", "password": "'"$OS_PASSWORD"'"} } }, "scope": { "project": { "domain": { "name": "Default" }, "name":  "'"$OS_PROJECT_NAME"'" } } }}' | python -m json.tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple method is with `fancyvrb` and `fvextra`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,fvextra}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[breaklines]
curl -v -s -X POST $OS_AUTH_URL/auth/tokens?nocatalog -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "auth": { "identity": { "methods": ["password"],"password": {"user": {"domain": {"name": "'"$OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME"'"},"name": "'"$OS_USERNAME"'", "password": "'"$OS_PASSWORD"'"} } }, "scope": { "project": { "domain": { "name": "Default" }, "name": "'"$OS_PROJECT_NAME"'" } } }}' | python -m json.tool
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The example uses `showframe` just for being sure the breaks respect the text width.

For also having syntax highlighting you can use `minted`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[breaklines]{bash}
curl -v -s -X POST $OS_AUTH_URL/auth/tokens?nocatalog -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "auth": { "identity": { "methods": ["password"],"password": {"user": {"domain": {"name": "'"$OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME"'"},"name": "'"$OS_USERNAME"'", "password": "'"$OS_PASSWORD"'"} } }, "scope": { "project": { "domain": { "name": "Default" }, "name": "'"$OS_PROJECT_NAME"'" } } }}' | python -m json.tool
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In both cases, the character after the break can be customized.

Comment: Great. Great. Thanks! Is there a way to make it default for Verbatim or minted?

Comment: @Reza For `fancyvrb` use `\fvset{breaklines}`, for `minted` it's `\setminted{breaklines}` (in the document preamble)

Comment: You are awesome!